# What is Google's auth Protocol ? did it changed from OAuth2 to OAuth 3?

Tags: php, search, protocols

What is Google's auth Protocol ? did it changed from OAuth2 to OAuth 3?
What is the purpose of this protocol?

Comment: Please at least search once on google before asking such question already a detailed documentation is available on google docs https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/AuthForWebApps

Answer (score 0):

It's still OAuth2 as you can see in the [Google docs](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2)

Answer (score 0):

Authentication with Google Accounts is based on OpenID Connect which is an extension of OAuth 2.0. It hasn't changed though Google is still working on phasing out the legacy OpenID 2.0 protocol in favor of OpenID Connect. OAuth 3 does not exist.